# How to escape while rendering a js.coffee file in response to an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a controller action that responds with a .js.coffee file, which is supposed to be supported in my version of Rails 3.2.12.  The problem is that something in the parsing is allowing user provided data to cause the javascript to fail.  I've simplified the example like this:

action.js.coffee file:

```
$('my_container').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'my_partial') %>")
```

my_partial.html.erb file contains just one line that should NOT be interpolated:

```
"#{this should not be evaluated}"
```

The javascript that actually gets rendered

```
$('my_container').append("\"" + (this(should(!be(evaluated)))) + "\"\n\n");
```

Whoa!  What is going on?  I can fix the problem by dropping the .coffee off of the filename, but this seems like a bug with Rails?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be interpolated? CS interpolates strings in double-quotes, and that looks more or less like what the CS code would be.

Comment: I simplified the example, in reality what was being interpolated was actually notes provided by a user on the system; he just happened to use #{} in his notes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the double quotes in the js.coffee file, but I'm still not sure its a bug.  Hopefully this will help someone else!

Changed:

`$('my_container').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'my_partial') %>")`

to

`$('my_container').append('<%= j render(:partial => 'my_partial') %>')`

Comment: Same thing I said before: CS strings in double-quotes are subject to interpolation. Single-quoted strings aren't.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The problem is that the `j` helper understands JavaScript but doesn't understand CoffeeScript. I don't think there is any helper solution that doesn't suck in one way or another. The only sensible thing (IMO) is to use single quotes everywhere unless you specifically need interpolation.

Comment: I've changed all my double quotes over to single. The real question is whether or not this could open up some exploits. In my case the user-provided content had #{} that exposed the interpolation.