# Rails: render partial in .coffee file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I would like to use coffeescript to `.append` a partial when a `.change` event occurs. The problem is that the code below does not render the partial when the `.change` event occurs, instead `<%= j render(:partial => 'participant_data').html_safe %>` is shown as text on the website.

```
$('input[type=number][id=quantity-select]').change ->
  $('#insert-here').append('<%= j render(:partial => \'participant_data\') %>')
  return
```

When I run `$('#insert-here').append("Test")` the word `Test` is shown on the page. So I am targeting the correct `div` and am able to `append` text, but I would like to render the partial instead of the text.

Please let me know how I need to change the code so that the partial renders.

Comment: I didn't work with coffee, but js.erb looks good. Could you please show us your coffee file and controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
$('#insert-here').append("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'participant_data')}")
```

Updated Answer: try with single quote.

```
$('#insert-here').append('<%= j render(:partial => \'participant_data\') %>')
```

Reference:

[How to escape while rendering a js.coffee file in response to an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955246/how-to-escape-while-rendering-a-js-coffee-file-in-response-to-an-action)

Comment: When I use this code I receive the following error message: `ReferenceError: escape_javascript is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I run the updated code I get the following error `ExecJS::RuntimeError SyntaxError: [stdin]:50:57: unexpected identifier`